# Calling Javascript Function in HTML with innerHTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML "sum.html" file seems not work with my "mathbox.js" file. I have declare it in the HTML head, however, when checking in Chrome console the num1 and num2 seems to work along with the sum by putting it sum = num1 + num2.

This is my Javascript function;

```
var num1 = Number(num1);
var num1 = Number(num1);
function calSum(){

    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    var add = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById("sum").inneHTML = add;
}
```

Below is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>

<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Matchbox</title>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="mathbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>




<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">First number:</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id = "num1" />
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
   <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calSum()">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">Second number:</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id ="num2" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">Sum:</td>
<td style="width:100px"> <input type="text" id ="sum" onclick="cal" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Try document.getElementById("sum").value = add;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
function calSum(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var add =  Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById("sum").value = add;
}
```

In your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function calSum(){
    alert('sasa');
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var add =  Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById("sum").value = add;
}
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">First number:</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id="num1" />
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
   <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calSum()">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">Second number:</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id="num2" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right">Sum:</td>
<td style="width:100px"> <input type="text" id ="sum" onclick="cal" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var num1 = Number(num1);  //called only once and it will suffer error
```

You can't parse it as global variable because *each time* you have to parse the string values as `number` and to fetch the value of textbox use **`value`** attribute.

```
function calSum(){
   var num1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
           // |_________used to parse the string as number type
   var num2 = +document.getElementById("num2").value;
           // |_________used to parse the string as number type
   var add = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById("sum").value= add;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying to remove global num1 and num2 outside of the function?

Comment: @user2985145 it is not within function, I'm saying there is no use in having `var num1 = Number(num1);
var num1 = Number(num1);` these lines.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It now works. You're guys are awesom

Comment: wow! +1 ... is it the safe way to parse the string to number with unary operator `+`?

Comment: Using the unary operator works, however, is it a good practise?

Comment: @user2985145 definitely yes it a good practice to use unary plus.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Yes you can use, to quote   [`The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use  **.innerHTML** for input type **text**

use as below :

```
document.getElementById("sum").value = add;
```

Replace YOur Function as below:

```
function calSum(){

    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var add = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

    //or you can use  var add =  Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById("sum").value= add;
}
```

Comment: parseInt may not always work without giving the base. as second parameter

Comment: @SajithNair - The second parameter is optional.  If omitted it defaults to a radix of `10`. If that is what the OP wants is not clear, but it will work.

Comment: @Steve This is not correct. Please go and check what is parseInt("0.2") and Number("0.2"). Please make sure you are not misleading the person who is asking doubt.

Comment: @SajithNair - You stated "parseInt may not always work without giving the base. as second parameter".  That is a wrong statement.  It ALWAYS works without a second parameter. Your example uses `parseInt` with a string representation of a `float`.  Of course that doesn't work... but that has nothing to do with the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks Steve & sajith for point me my mistake. i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("num1")` returns a string. You need to convert that to a number before adding using `Number()`. Otherwise it will do string concatenation. Also instead of using `.innerHTML` you have to use `.value`.

```
function calSum(){

    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    var add = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
    document.getElementById("sum").value = add;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id ="sum" onclick="cal" />
```

`input` element doesn't have `innerHTML` property. You have to use `value` property in your Javascript.

Just like this ...

```
document.getElementById("sum").value = add;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the input box we are using value not innerHTML , innerHTML is used for the containers like div,td etc..

so please change your function

```
function calSum(){
   var num1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
   var num2 = +document.getElementById("num2").value;
   var add = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById("sum").value= add;
}
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, this would do string concatenation. You probably want to make sure `num1` and `num2` are numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as:

```
function calSum()
{
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;   
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;   

    if(!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2))
    {
        add = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
    }   

    document.getElementById("sum").value = add;     
}
```